# CalendarView.setTime issues

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, calendarview

I'm having issues trying to use .setTime on a CalendarView object, see code below.

```
package com.example.calendar_test;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
CalendarView cv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    long startDate;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cv = (CalendarView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
    startDate = cv.getDate();
    cv.setDate(cv.getDate());
    final Context context = this;

    cv.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener(){
         public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
             Date selDate = new Date();
             selDate.setMonth(month);
             selDate.setYear(year);
             selDate.setDate(dayOfMonth);
             selDate.setTime(selDate.getTime());

             view.setDate(selDate.getTime());

             Date d = new Date();
             d.setMonth(2);
             d.setYear(2014);
             d.setDate(22);
             d.setTime(d.getTime());

             if(view.getDate() == d.getTime()){
                 Toast.makeText(context, "You hit the 22", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }

         }

    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

When I run I get this message when selecting a date. 
02-17 15:50:30.501: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1098): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Time not between Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 1900 and Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 EST 2100

Blowing up on view.setDate(selDate.getTime());

I don't quite understand why selDate.getTime() isn't a valid long for view.setDate()

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `Date` object, its `year` value is current year minus 1900. That's a valid value for calculating number of milliseconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00. When you modify `year` value of `Date` object by `year` from arguments list, those milliseconds are out of range, because that `year` in argument list, is just current year (without minus 1900).

You should replace

`selDate.setYear(year);` and `selDate.setYear(2014);`

with

`selDate.setYear(year-1900);` and `selDate.setYear(114);`

Comment: While this worked, what's the best way to work with Dates in Java/Android?  Preferred objects?

Comment: Personally I use `Date` and `Calendar`